# How to separate entity's primary key from base class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, clean-architecture

I want to accomplish clean architecture with EF Core.
I trid to separate primary key from base class, but it failed with below exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A key cannot be configured on 'ManagerEntity' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'Manager'. If you did not intend for 'Manager' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not referenced by a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation on a type that is included in the model.'

#### Core

```cs
public class Manager
{
    public Manager(Guid identifier, string email)
    {
        Identifier = identifier;
        Email = email;
    }

    public Guid Identifier { get; }
    public string Email { get; }

    public void FixPrinter(Printer printer)
    {
        printer.IsOutOfControl = true;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Printer
{
    public Printer(Guid token)
    {
        Token = token;
        Manager = null;
        IsOutOfControl = false;
    }

    public Guid Token { get; }

    public Manager? Manager { get; set; }

    public bool IsOutOfControl { get; set; }
}
```

#### Infrastructure

```cs
public class ApplicationContext
    : DbContext
{
    // ...

    public DbSet<ManagerEntity> ManagerSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PrinterEntity> PrinterSet { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ManagerEntityConfiguration(Database));
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PrinterEntityConfiguration(Database));
    }
}
```

##### Configure `Manager`

```cs
public sealed class ManagerEntity
    : Manager
{
    public ManagerEntity(string email)
        : base(Guid.Empty, email)
    {
    }

    // Primary key for database.
    public long Id { get; }
}
```

```cs
internal sealed class ManagerEntityConfiguration
    : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ManagerEntity>
{
    private readonly DatabaseFacade _database;

    public ManagerEntityConfiguration(DatabaseFacade database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ManagerEntity> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Property(e => e.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        // The exception occurs here.
        builder
            .HasKey(e => e.Id);

        // ...
    }
}
```

##### Configure `Printer`

```cs
public sealed class PrinterEntity
    : Printer
{
    public PrinterEntity()
        : base(Guid.Empty)
    {
    }

    // Primary key for database.
    public long Id { get; }
}
```

```cs
internal sealed class PrinterEntityConfiguration
    : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PrinterEntity>
{
    private readonly DatabaseFacade _database;

    public PrinterEntityConfiguration(DatabaseFacade database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PrinterEntity> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Property(e => e.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder
            .HasKey(e => e.Id);

        // ...
    }
}
```

#### Web API

```cs
app.MapPost("/printer", async (ApplicationContext context) =>
{
    PrinterEntity printer = new()
    {
        Manager = new ManagerEntity("master@google.com"),
    };

    await context.PrinterSet.AddAsync(printer);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return printer;
});
```

Should I architect it by using **interface**, not **inheritance**?

At **Core**,

```cs
public interface IPrinter
{
    public Manager? Manager { get; set; }
}
```

At **Infrastructure**,

```cs
public sealed class PrinterEntity : IPrinter
{
    // ...
}
```

[Github source code](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/71060653)

Comment: The trigger is the navigation; `public Manager? Manager { get; set; }`. So now EF Core thinks you want that type in your model...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes, your right. So I am currently looking for a way to use `ManagerEntity` for relationships, instead of `Manager` in business logic domain code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, [@roji](https://github.com/roji)!

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27421#issuecomment-1034762908

This is likely happening because you're mapping both Manager and ManagerEntity in your model, which means you're configuring [inheritance mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) (i.e. EF thinks you intend to store both Manager and ManagerEntity instances in the database). With inheritance mapping, the key must be specified at the root.

However, it seems like you only want the class separation on the .NET side, without needing any actual hierarchy, so make sure you are not mapping the base class (Manager in the above). See the minimal code sample below.

```cs
await using var ctx = new BlogContext();
await ctx.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    // Uncomment the below to make the exception appear
    // public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ManagerEntity> ManagerEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=test;User=SA;Password=Abcd5678;Connect Timeout=60;ConnectRetryCount=0")
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ManagerEntity>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
    }
}

public class Manager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ManagerEntity : Manager
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

However... if the goal is simply not to expose an Id property on Manager, there are simpler ways to do that rather than introducing a .NET hierarchy. You can have a private _id field instead, which would be used by EF Core but not otherwise exposed in your application, keeping your data model clean ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations#field-only-properties)). Alternatively, you can have an Id [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties), removing the field/property from your CLR type altogether.